# Why does Irileth hate me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim today and went to turn a bounty in to Avenicci and Irileth immediately began attacking me once I got within her detection range. I reloaded, several times, and she attacked me every single time. Eventually I ran past, leaving Lidia to distract the PMSing dark elf and the guards while I went, found the steward, and turned in my bounty. After that it took several more minutes of hiding and then finally an attack on Irileth to disable her that let me get Lidia away from her but now I'm afraid to even enter Whiterun because Irileth is in the middle of the town and still very, very hostile.

Is there any way to fix this or am I just going to go ahead with my tentative plan to be an Altmer Stormcloak (the irony tickles)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this is a possible bug, in which Irileth's aggression value can be set to 1 for no apparent reason. Since you've stated that she's actually started attacking you, there is only one possible solution.

Commit any minor crime, such as assaulting a guard, and then clear your bounty. If all goes well, this should cause NPCs to stop attacking you.

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Irileth#Bugs

Comment: I think I may have stumbled across this fix on accident shortly after I posted this. Thank you for the assistance and the assistance of everyone after this.